# Existe-il un verbe synonyme à s'abonner/souscrire qui impliquerait par défaut la gratuité ?

Tags: synonymes, demande-de-mot

Suite à des retours pour une interface utilisateur, il est parfois assez compliqué pour certaines personnes, lorsqu'elles arrivent sur un site internet, de savoir si le bouton sur lequel elles vont cliquer va leur demander un moyen de paiement. Exemple:

> "Je m'abonne" *dans le cas d'une newsletter.*

Souscrire pose le même problème.

> Souscrire *(Larousse)* : *S'engager à contribuer financièrement à quelque chose*, mais aussi *Donner son adhésion, son approbation à quelque chose*

Je cherche un synonyme qui impliquerait la **gratuité** de s'abonner à une newsletter, à un fil d'actualité, majoritairement à destination de personnes âgées ou qui ne sont pas familières avec internet, tout en restant simple et concis.

*Suivre* est un peu ambigu.
Le plus simple que j'ai pu trouver: *Me garder informé(e)*.

Comment: Il y a des abonnements payants et des abonnements gratuits. Même avant l'internet, les gens âgées avaient l'habitude des abonnements. Abonnement gratuit. Oú est le problème??

Answer (score 1):

**M'inscrire** me semble convenir. Son sens est d'ajouter son nom à une liste et n'implique généralement aucun paiement (même si on peut aussi inscrire son enfant pour un séjour/colonie de vacance impliquant un paiement par la suite).

D'ailleurs il me semble que s'inscrire à une newletter/ lettre d'information est tout à fait courant, même si l'on rencontre peut-être plus couramment **Me désinscrire** qui figure en pied de page de la plupart des e-mail commerciaux.

j'ajouterais cependant de **s'abonner** sera bien compris comme gratuit s'il est clairement question d'une newsletter/lettre d'information

Comment: +1 pour inscrire, qui est une bonne alternative si on veut éviter "Suivre". Il est vrai que "s'abonner" va généralement être compris comme gratuit dans ce cas, mais c'est tout de même plus ambigu que "Suivre" ou "S'inscrire".

Comment: @Simon Le problème avec suivre pour le cas particulier de cette question est qu'on semblait privilégier l'utilisation de la première personne: «Je suis» (donc je pense??) Je crois qu'autrement, «suivre» eût été la meilleure proposition. La première personne fait pencher la balance vers «m'inscrire» (pour moi du moins...).

Answer (score 0):

Une petite variation de ta proposition :

> ***Me tenir informé(e)**.*

On la trouve couramment dans les formulaires de pages web et elle implique que cette information sera offerte gratuitement.

Comment: J'ai continué de chercher et je pense qu'il est compliqué de faire plus concis malheureusement

Comment: Tu peux gagner trois lettres avec **Rester informé(e)**.

Answer (score 0):

*Suivre* semble être le mot parfait pour ce que tu décris. C'est un mot qui est utilisé sur la majorité des plateformes en ligne pour cette fonction. C'est tellement commun que la définition est aussi dans les dictionaires. Voici la [définition du larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/suivre/75316):

> En parlant d’une personne inscrite sur un réseau social, recevoir volontairement les informations publiques émanant du profil d’un internaute ou d’un site Web dès leur mise en ligne : Suivre un homme politique sur un réseau.

La définition parle d'un réseau social, mais le concept reste le même: on veut "suivre l'information et la recevoir dès la mise en ligne". Il est assez difficile de trouver un autre mot puisque c'est le mot qui correspond, mais voici quelques alternatives: observer, surveiller, s'informer, notifier.